# How to tell customer status of invoice based on cell change

Tags: google-sheets-api

I have a google spreadsheet with columns ... customer invoice number, email address and status
I want to send the customer an email when the status changes to different statuses eg processing , building, dispatched
is this possible?

or can i get an app where the customer enters their invoice number and it gives them results that are on that row for that invoice number?

I am just wanting to keep customers up to date and all my data sits in google spreadsheets

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple triggers which fires when cell value is changed in the sheet.

[Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#:%7E:text=The%20onEdit(e)%20trigger%20runs,last%20time%20it%20was%20edited)

Comment: Hello, thankyou for reply, i am new to this, and need a simple way to tell my customers where their order is up to  i have a drop down that i change to processing, building, dispatched, for each customer is a line, want to email them when i change the dropdown. OR if a customer can login somewhere and put in their invioce and it tells them their status of that dropdown